# Using topic_tools transform to publish more complex types

Tags: ros, topic-tools, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to use topic_tools/transform to publish messages that are slightly more complex than [what the examples show in the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/transform), in order to avoid having to write a node.

For example (this might be a bad example), I would like the transform node to subscribe to a TwistStamped message, then create a new TwistStamped message with twist.linear.x equal to the magnitude of the subscribed linear velocity (which only needs a simple math function).

I figured out how to have transform publish the Float on its own, and can also figure out how to publish a Vector, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to publish a Twist or a TwistStamped. I keep getting errors, probably due to my incorrect syntax. But I can't find any examples online. I'm also not sure how to put a header into the published message.

If transform isn't the right tool to use, is there something else I should be using? Or perhaps it's just better to write my own node after all?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261935/using-topic_tools-transform-to-publish-more-complex-types/) by [9a3eedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27142/9a3eedi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2017-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I always find topic_tools/transform very useful, but somewhat difficult to use. I always helps me to write the expressions in a text editor, so that you can experiment and jump around a little bit more. I *think* this is the transform you are after: I am not able to test it right now, but you'll get the idea.

```
rosrun topic_tools transform /ts /tsnew geometry_msgs/TwistStamped \
  'geometry_msgs.msg.TwistStamped( \
    header=m.header,  \
    twist=geometry_msgs.msg.Twist( \
      linear=geometry_msgs.msg.Vector3( \
        numpy.linalg.norm([m.twist.linear.x, m.twist.linear.y, m.twist.linear.z]),  \
        0.0,  \
        0.0)))'  \
   --import geometry_msgs
```

I have split it into several lines for clarity. Few notes, the imports can be a bit finicky and it's useful to test with the python interpreter.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-05-17**:
I'm impressed that you can do this with topic_tools/transform, but it's probably more readable to write a small ROS node that does it.

**Comment by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) on 2017-05-18**:
I agree. It's usually not the easiest way, but once you get the hang of it you can jot them down quite quickly and it can be useful as a quick tool.

**Comment by [NEET](https://answers.ros.org/users/41884/neet/) on 2019-05-28**:
Amazing! Really useful and solved my problem, thanks!